# Operand type clash: varbinary is incompatible with text

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I have a file upload control by which user can upload image file to database table.

currently i am using to RDBMS 1)Postgresql and 2) SQL server

**in my postgres database table column for file i use datatypeas bytea
in my sql server database table column for file i use datatype as text**

this is my method

```
public void uploadRentProofDeclaration(final MultipartFile declarationForm,
        final int rentProofInfoId, int year) {

    String updateSql = "update plit_landlordinfo" + year
            + " set filename=?,declarationform=? where cid=?";
    getJdbcTemplate().execute(updateSql, new PreparedStatementCallback() {
        public Object doInPreparedStatement(
                final PreparedStatement pSstatement) throws SQLException,
                DataAccessException {
            pSstatement.setString(1, declarationForm.getOriginalFilename());

            try {
                pSstatement.setBinaryStream(2, new ByteArrayInputStream(
                        declarationForm.getBytes()), declarationForm
                        .getBytes().length);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            pSstatement.setInt(3, rentProofInfoId);

            pSstatement.execute();
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

this code is working fine with postgresql as well as oracle also but when i my trying to upload image file in sql server i am getting this error.

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [update plit_landlordinfo2011 set filename=?,declarationform=? where cid=?]; Operand type clash: varbinary is incompatible with text; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Operand type clash: varbinary is incompatible with text
```

can any one help me where i am doing wrong and what is the solution

Comment: My guess here. Field type is "text"

Comment: yes in sql server datatype is text

Comment: So use setString() method instead of setBinaryStream() or change field type to "image" or varbinary

Comment: I have fixed the problem by changing data type to image in sql server.